# Column count does not match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

While deleting, getting error like Column count does not match value count at row 1

Mysql Query:-

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.id IN (SELECT cust_id FROM customers_info)
```

Comment: use GROUP_CONCAT() in sub query to get cust_id from customers_info table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM customers WHERE customers.id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cust_id) FROM customers_info)
```